# How do i loop this so it asks whether or not the user wants to input another variable and runs the program again

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
Console.WriteLine("Welcome please use this to convert your units");


//request input from user for choice of conversion

Console.WriteLine("Please select one of the following conversion options:");
Console.WriteLine("A - Converting from inches to centimeters");
Console.WriteLine("B - Converting from yard to meters");
Console.WriteLine("C - Converting from miles to km");
userinput = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


//Create table for possible inputs

switch (char.ToUpper(userinput))
{
  case 'A':
    {
    

      //request amount wanted to convert

      Console.WriteLine("Enter the amount of inches");
      inches = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
      //read input then do math 
      cm = inches / 0.39370;
      

      //release output

      Console.WriteLine($"inches in cm is {cm}");
```

Comment: So.... do you know how to write a loop? If not, start here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/tutorials/branches-and-loops-local

Comment: Your code is incomplete, you have only one case there and that is not even closed. Provide more code and more details to what you want accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a [do while loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/do).

```
bool shouldContinue;

do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome please use this to convert your units");
    
    // Logic here

    Console.WriteLine(@"Continue (y = yes, n = no)");

    shouldContinue = Console
        .ReadLine()
        ?.ToLowerInvariant()
        .Trim()
        .Equals(@"y") ?? false;
} while (shouldContinue);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(true) 
{  
     ....
     Console.WriteLine("X - Exit");
    
     ,,,
     switch()
     {
           ...

     case X:
          return;  // or restart application or clear all lines and break
      }    
}
```